# Rewriting $\sum_\limits{t=\alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha} F_2(\alpha-t,\mu_2)P_1(t,\mu_1) $ without sigma?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-analysis, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with Poisson distribution, $F_2(y,\mu_2)$ be the Poisson CDF of $Y$ with mean $\mu_2$ and $P_1(x,\mu_1)$ be the Poisson PMF of $X$ with mean $\mu_1$. How to rewrite the following expression in terms of $F_1$,$F_2$,$P_1$,$P_2$, $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ and ...  in order to get rid of sigma ($\Sigma$)?

\begin{equation}
\sum_{t=\alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha} F_2(\alpha-t,\mu_2)P_1(t,\mu_1)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=\alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha} F_2(\alpha-t,\mu_2)P_1(t,\mu_1) &=\sum_{t=\alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha}P(Y \le \alpha -t) P(X =t)\\
&=\sum_{t=\alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha}P(Y \le \alpha -t,\,X =t)\\
&=\sum_{t=\alpha-\beta+1}^{\alpha}P(X=t,\, X+Y \le \alpha)\\
&=P(\alpha-\beta+1\le X\le \alpha,\, X+Y \le \alpha).
\end{align*}